# SQL null values inner join

Tags: sql

I would like to only include a comparison on an inner join if the value is not null.  E.g. I am comparing addresses some addresses have the same house number street address and tag but have a distinct apartment number, but other addresses don't have apartment numbers associated with them so the value is null.  These values don't get joined.

A left outer join won't work because I need to join data associated with the values that have null apartment values.  Any ideas?

```
select * from address a
inner join ma_address ma
    on a.number=ma.number
    and a.street=ma.street
    and a.tag=ma.tag
    and a.apt=ma.apt
```

Thanks,

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Using `SELECT *` from multiple tables can lead to confusion. It's much better to be specific in your `SELECT` criteria

Comment: u can use union as well

Comment: If you're using MySQL, you can use the null-safe equality operator, `<=>`.

Comment: You could also change your schema so these fields have a default value of `''` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Most rdbms beside MySQL will allow you to use `a.apt IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ma.apt`

Comment: @Barmar Just have to be careful of Oracle. Treats empty strings as `NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in SQL, `NULL` does not equal `NULL`. Try something like this for each join criteria

```
(a.<col> = ma.<col> OR (a.<col> IS NULL AND ma.<col> IS NULL))
```

Comment: This answer worked very well.  Another thing that tripped me up was the column was populated with the string value 'NULL' instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

**A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown**. A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.
Null values generally indicate data that is unknown, not applicable, or that the data will be added later. For example, a customer's middle initial may not be known at the time the customer places an order.
Following is information about nulls:
1. **To test for null values in a query, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL in the WHERE clause**.
2. When query results are viewed in SQL Server Management Studio Code editor, null values are shown as NULL in the result set.
3. Null values can be inserted into a column by explicitly stating NULL in an INSERT or UPDATE statement, by leaving a column out of an INSERT statement, or when adding a new column to an existing table by using the ALTER TABLE statement.
4. Null values cannot be used for information that is required to distinguish one row in a table from another row in a table, such as primary keys.

---

Source: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)